unable to use snap to install netbeans on mx-linux
I'm trying to install netbeans following the official step-by-step but when i try sudo snap install snapd I get
error: cannot communicate with server: 
Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/snapd": 
dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

and since I have init and not systemctl when I try to /etc/init.d/snapd start I get
AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled but some kernel features are missing: dbus, network
2024/07/23 00:19:07.176454 overlord.go:263: Acquiring state lock file
2024/07/23 00:19:07.176548 overlord.go:268: Acquired state lock file
2024/07/23 00:19:07.221892 daemon.go:247: started snapd/2.57.6-1+b5 (series 16; classic; devmode) debian/12 (amd64) linux/6.1.0-22-amd64.
2024/07/23 00:19:07.233605 daemon.go:340: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
2024/07/23 00:19:12.309298 daemon.go:521: gracefully waiting for running hooks
2024/07/23 00:19:12.309341 daemon.go:523: done waiting for running hooks
2024/07/23 00:19:12.311715 overlord.go:504: Released state lock file
daemon stop requested to wait for socket activation


I've even asked chatGPT and it suggest installing another kernel I just want netbeans installed in my machine is it not possible?
